# Left margin on tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have some textfields in my tableviewcell. The left margin is not aligned with the separator at the bottom. I've tried setting the `indentation level` to 3 but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've also ticked `Preserve Superview Margins`. Is there a way to get the left margin to the default value?

[image]

Comment: let me know whether my answer worked for you @Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Select UITableView cell in Storyboard, change Separater from Default Insets to Custom Insets and set Left to 0.

Refer following image for same:-

[image]

**Note:-** Default Insets specify Left to 15.